# Find empty cell in a specified columns and color the empty cells "red"

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to determine empty column cells and color those empty cell "red". However I'm new to VBA and don't quite know the process how to do it. Can someone explain or help me? Thank you in advance.

Due to privacy, I just attached the sample result here. But this is the function that I'm looking for.

Sample:

Check the empty cells in Column1 and Column3 (until last cell of the column), then highlight those empty cells in "red".

[image: This is the sample result]

Only limited column cells can be determined empty and highlighted red.

Comment: Why not using simple conditional formatting for that?

Comment: Please share the code you've got so we can see where the data is located (workbook, worksheet, table).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a table on `Sheet1`, name the table `tblTest` and try the below:

```
Sub Find_Empty_Cells()

    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim i As Long
    
    'Declare table name
    Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("tblTest")
  
    With tbl
        'Loop Through Every Row except header in Table
        For i = 1 To tbl.Range.Rows.Count - 1
            'Check column 1
            If .DataBodyRange(i, 1).Value = "" Then
                .DataBodyRange(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            End If
            'Check column 3
            If .DataBodyRange(i, 3).Value = "" Then
                .DataBodyRange(i, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            End If
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much for this. I'll try this code pattern.

Comment: What if I also need to check and highlight cells from the other worksheets (same workbook). Should I use the switch function to determine which worksheet needs to be checked?

Comment: @mitsuha you should change sheet name (`Sheet1`) and table name (`tblTest`) from `Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("tblTest")`

Comment: Oh I see. It's the same code pattern but with different sheet name and table name.              Sorry I forgot to mention on my question that there are 3 sheets that need to be checked at the same time.

Comment: @mitsuha you could create a function with the above code and pass as parameters sheet name and table name in case you want to perform the check at any point individually, or you could loop all sheets in the workbook at once

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to loop through all the cells.

You can use `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` to identify all empty cells in a range, and you can use `Columns(1)` and `Columns(3)` to locate the 1st and 3rd columns of a given range. Combining those two ranges will give you all cells in columns 1 and 3 that are empty.. so just colour those red.

```
Sub Colour_Empty_Cells_Red()
    Dim empty_cells As Range
    On Error Resume Next
        With Range("A1").CurrentRegion
            Set empty_cells = Union(.Columns(1), .Columns(3)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not (empty_cells Is Nothing) Then empty_cells.Interior.Color = vbRed
End Sub
```

[image]

---

To run the code on each worksheet within a workbook, create a `For Each..` loop that cycles through each worksheet and then include that changing worksheet reference in your Range("A1") use:

```
Sub Colour_Empty_Cells_Red()
    Dim empty_cells As Range, ws As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
            Set empty_cells = Union(.Columns(1), .Columns(3)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        End With
        If Not (empty_cells Is Nothing) Then empty_cells.Interior.Color = vbRed
    Next
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Will also try this one. What if I also need to check the other sheets from the same workbook at the same time.

Comment: Do you want it to run on **every** sheet in the workbook? Or from a list of worksheet names?

Comment: Yes, on every sheet in the workbook. From sheet1 to sheet3. All empty cells of columns 1 and 3 should be highlighted.

Comment: I've added a variation of the code at the bottom of my answer to solve this for you.

Comment: Thank you so much. Sorry I have another question. How about if I want to start checking from a specific row. Can I add the row number where the columns are?  "Union(.Columns(1), .Columns(3)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)'

Comment: You would probably want to use `.Intersect(Range)` for that - e.g. to only include rows 5 to 500 -> `Set empty_cells = Intersect(.Range("5:500"),Union(.Columns(1), .Columns(3......` Have a go and if you need help with `Intersect` I'd suggest a new question.